# VBA to seach string in cell and create new data in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

The task I'm trying to complete is as follows: 
Each of the letters represent a specific training an individual has received. The problem being we have some symbols that after you achieve more than one, become another symbol. So what I need to do is break down the symbols in a cell, and have them returned to their full values.

Example:

```
    D2: {@DWRZ}
    R= B+X
    Result after code: {@DWBXZ}
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this in VBA, I'm assuming something like a string search and if R is found then write to a new cell the current contents without the R and add BX. Thoughts?

Comment: You could just use SUBSTITUTE() function in excel.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about this function after using Excel since 07 :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how your data is structured, it's a little difficult to code a fully functional solution. For instance, it would be helpful to know where "R = B+X" is defined in your table relative to "{@DWRZ}". That being said, here is a general solution that I think might work for you.

```
Function ReplaceValues(OldString As String)
    n = 3 ' <----------------Adjust the number of replacements as needed.
    ReDim arr(1 To n, 1 To 2)  '                                 ^
    arr(1, 1) = "R": arr(1, 2) = "BX"   '                        |
    arr(2, 1) = "--": arr(2, 2) = "--"  '                        |
    arr(3, 1) = "--": arr(3, 2) = "--"  '                        |
    '  <------------Add more definitions as needed... ---------- +
    For x = 1 To n
        If InStr(1, OldString, arr(x, 1)) Then 'If the leter "R" is found in "@DWRZ"
            NewString = Replace(OldString, arr(x, 1), arr(x, 2)) 'Replace it with "BX"
        End If
    Next
    ReplaceValues = NewString
End Function
```

If you place this function in your project, then you will be able to call it in the same way that you would any of the functions built into Excel. For example `=ReplaceValues(A1)` where cell A1 contains your string, "{@DWRZ}" Hopefully this is useful to you.